# SQLite renumber ID using cycle

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hello I have table with many inserted row. I need to renumber all row by id and order them.

I have found this code but it does not work for me.

```
SET @i = 100;
UPDATE "main"."Categories" SET ID = (@i := @i +1) WHERE "Name" = "White";
ALTER TABLE "main"."Categories" AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

So using code above I expected renumbered all records that have name - white and start insert them from 100 with increment 1. But it is not work for me. Maybe there is some problem in my code but maybe it is a difference between SQL and SQLite query.

This how I created table:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Free NUMERIC)
```

I hope there is already made solution how to do it because I don't want to do it manually :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is not standard SQL.

SQLite does not have many programming constructs because it is designed to be an embedded database where it is more natural to have the logic in the host language.

If you want to do this in SQL, try the following:
First, create a temporary table so that we have an autoincrement column that can be used for counting:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_ids(i INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, old_id INTEGER);
```

Insert a dummy record to ensure that the next new record starts at `100`, then insert all the IDs of the `Categories` table that you want to change:

```
INSERT INTO new_ids VALUES(99, NULL);
INSERT INTO new_ids SELECT NULL, id FROM "Categories" WHERE "Name" = 'White';
DELETE FROM new_ids WHERE i = 99;
```

Then we can change all these IDs in the original table:

```
UPDATE "Categories"
  SET id = (SELECT i FROM new_ids WHERE old_id = "Categories".id)
  WHERE id IN (SELECT old_id FROM new_ids);
DROP TABLE new_ids;
```