# Deleting order, SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to `SQLiteDatabase` and I'd like to know one thing. If I have multiple rows in table (id column is `autoincrement` integer), let's say there are 7 rows. Then, I delete row with ID 4. Will be my table look like 1,2,3,5,6,7 or it's gonna be from 1 to 6? If ids will be like in first case(1,2,3,5,6,7) then how to make them from 1 to 6?
Thank you.

Comment: You may read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301817/sqlite-renumber-id-using-cycle

Comment: why would you want it to be from 1 to 6?

Comment: Your table will look like `1,2,3,5,6,7`. But this is really not influent. And you should never renumber your ids, in order not to break the associations in other tables. Why are you so concerned about? This is something that only new database users try to fight (I did in my times, then I understood that there's a logic why it is so).